# Converting HTML & Script Code of the YouGlish API to React Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a React application which uses YouGlish Javascript API. In my application, I want to open a video screen by clicking a button that calls the YouGlish functions. Here is the Button implementation:

```
<div id="buttons">
   <button id="youglish" onClick={() => YouglishWidget()} style={{ display: youglish ? 'block' : 'none'}}>YouGlish</button>
</div>
```

And the function, `YouglishWidget()`, which is called by button is:

```
export function YouglishWidget() {

  console.log("YouglishWidget is called");
  
  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://youglish.com/public/emb/widget.js";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var views = 0, curTrack = 0, totalTracks = 0;

  function onFetchDone(event) {

    console.log("onFetchDone is called");

    if (event.totalResult == 0){
      alert("No result found");
    } 
    else totalTracks = event.totalResult; 
  }

  function onVideoChange(event) {
    curTrack = event.trackNumber;
    views = 0;
  }

  function onCaptionConsumed(event) {
    if (++views < 3) {
      widget.replay();
    } else if (curTrack < totalTracks) {
      widget.next();
    }
  }

  function onYouglishAPIReady() {

    console.log("onYouglishAPIReady is called");
    
    const widget = new YG.Widget("widget-1", {
      width: 640,
      components: 9,
      events: {
        onFetchDone: onFetchDone,
        onVideoChange: onVideoChange,
        onCaptionConsumed: onCaptionConsumed,
      },
    });
    
    widget.fetch("courage", "english");
  }
  
  return (
    <div id="widget-1"></div>
  );
}
```

I tried to transform HTML & javascript code from the this URL ([Javascript API Reference](https://youglish.com/api/doc/js-api)). When I click the button, nothing returns from `YouglishWidget()`. What should I do to return the screen when I click the button?

`YouglishWidget()` function returns nothing.

Comment: Is `YouglishWidget` supposed to be a React component? The `YouglishWidget`, if it is a component, returns an empty div `<div id="widget-1"></div>`. There's no React state or anything that is updated to trigger React to rerender the component. You can't return JSX from asynchronous callbacks and expect them to be rendered anywhere. What exactly are you expecting this code to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, it is a React component. I would like to thank you for your response. How could I write the React state to trigger return statement? When I click the button,  I want open a video window which is under the button.

Comment: I think you should first try to restructure the code/logic such that the `<div id="widget-1"></div>` is rendered to the DOM as part of the normal component render, and then see if you really need any React state. It *may* be enough to query the DOM for that element and call those methods. It's not common or advised to do this in React, but sometimes it's unavoidable when working with other non-React 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try as you write. My intention was to tranform the javascript API of the YouGlish website by writing a simple export function. I could not imagine to consider rendering to the Dom.